# What's the outline extension shown in vscode release notes?

Tags: vscode-extensions

[image: vscode outline extension image]

I think it looks better than default outline shown in explore.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's something very special.

You can achieve the same by,

1. From VS Code window title bar, click "Toggle Secondary Side Bar" to show the right hand side bar.
2. As it asks you to "Drag a view here to display", you can drag the OUTLINE view from the primary side bar onto this secondary bar.

Then it looks like,

[image]